# What is the best practice for executing M threads, N per time?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have many threads and, if I let the .NET runtime to decide how many threads to run simultaneously, it will often trigger an OutOfMemoryException as the operations are really heavy.

Every time a request arrives at my server, I need to run a thread. I'd like to do a `ThreadPool.EnqueueWorkItem` but saying: Please, do not run more than 2 of these at a given time. Wait for one of them to finish before starting the next.

What is the best practice in this situation.

Comment: BlockingCollection lets you set a max.  But it does not sound like you are looking for a producer consumer model.

Comment: can you instead of threads run executables ? every executable will run like separate process and have much more memory available for allocation. but there are always your concrete server setup concerns, for both cases.

Comment: BTW, what is your communication layer in the server?

Comment: A best practice is to never wait for the slowest thread to finish before you start more.  So scratch the "N per time" requirement, doesn't sound like you need it anyway.  A semaphore is the ideal sync object to implement rate limiting.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads` Method.

**From MSDN:**

> Sets the number of requests to the thread pool that can be active
>   concurrently. All requests above that number remain queued until
>   thread pool threads become available.

**Important remarks:**

> If the common language runtime is hosted, for example by Internet
>   Information Services (IIS) or SQL Server, the host can limit or
>   prevent changes to the thread pool size. Use caution when changing the
>   maximum number of threads in the thread pool. While your code might
>   benefit, the changes might have an adverse effect on code libraries
>   you use. Setting the thread pool size too large can cause performance
>   problems. If too many threads are executing at the same time, the task
>   switching overhead becomes a significant factor.

In addition, because you mentioned `OutOfMemoryException`, try to release unused resources (e.g. call `Dispose()` if available).

**UPDATE:**

As @erikH commented, It is **important** to note that this ability will limit the entire thread pool, but if part of a larger application, this will limit also all the fast tasks when some heavy tasks requires all available thread pool threads.

Comment: (not downvoter but...) This will limit the entire thread pool. But if part of a larger application, this will limit also all the fast tasks when some heavy tasks requires all available thread pool threads.

Comment: @erikH You mean that whereever the threadpool will come in use in the current application, the limitation will take effect?

Comment: Yes... Thank you for the answer, but I cannot limit the entire ThreadPool.

Answer (score 0):

I would write something like this

```
static int MAX_THREADS = 3;
static SemaphoreSlim _Semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(MAX_THREADS, MAX_THREADS);

void ProcessRequest(Action action)
{
    _Semaphore.Wait();
    Task.Run(action)
        .ContinueWith(t => _Semaphore.Release());
}
```

Comment: Every time you call _Semaphore.Wait, a thread will halt, waiting for your semaphore. Threads are expensive system resources: you shouldn't waste them this way.

Comment: @Soonts who says that ProcessRequest will be invoked from different threads.. BTW: calling thread will not be blocked if MAX_THREADS tasks are not running.

Comment: This is the correct answer, he starts the thread *after* waiting.

Comment: If 1000 clients will call your ProcessRequest at the same time, 1000 threads will be created, and 998 of them will just wait for that semaphore. 1000 threads = 1GB RAM in stack sizes + enormous overhead to create that many.

Comment: @Soonts No, 1000 threads will **not** be created. (of course, unless OP creates a new thread for every request explicitely. )

Comment: When IIS will discover all worker threads are busy running your code (actually just sleeping in your _Semaphore.Wait), it'll create more threads to keep processing the incoming requests.

Comment: @Soonts So you are sure OP uses IIS, not TcpListener, HttpListener, ServiceHost, WebServiceHost or similar.

Comment: They all, including IIS, rely on the CLR thread pool. When you use threads that lavishly on a server under the load, you only have 2 choices: (1) your server stops responding to requests, because all the threads are busy sleeping in your semaphore (2) More threads are spawned.

Comment: `They all, including IIS, rely on the CLR thread pool` Please don't post your assumptions as fact.

Comment: Every time a client stops in your _Semaphore.Wait, that thread becomes completely useless until the semaphore is released. If you want to process more requests, you need more threads — regardless on the I/O API, regardless on the thread pool implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You should use e.g. [AsyncSemaphore primitive](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/02/12/10266983.aspx).

Here's the code (untested):

```
static readonly AsyncSemaphore s_semaphore = new AsyncSemaphore( 2 );

static async Task EnqueueAction( Action act )
{
    await s_semaphore.WaitAsync();
    try
    {
        await Task.Run( act );
    }
    finally
    {
        s_semaphore.Release();
    }
}
```